# Exponential function in R returning 0 as a value

Tags: r, exp

who can tell me a solution to avoid a result of 0 in y in R program

> y= 1-(1/(1+exp(-x)))

exp(-x) is > 0 but for x values like 100 the result of y is 0.
I need to get small numbers > 0 to apply log(y) without getting -Inf result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this with some simple maths:

```
x <- 1
1-(1/(1+exp(-x)))
#[1] 0.2689414
1/(exp(x) + 1)
#[1] 0.2689414

x <- 100
1-(1/(1+exp(-x)))
#[1] 0
1/(exp(x) + 1)
#[1] 3.720076e-44
```

If you are interested in log(y) for large values of x, just ignore the `+ 1`, y is approximately exp(-x) with a very small error for large x. Thus, log(y) == -x for large x.

Your teacher probably wants you to do the maths.

Comment: thanks for the answer it worked
but for another line
Exp(x)/(Exp(x)+1)
For x=100 for exemple it returns 1
even 1/(1+Exp(-x)) returnx 1 how to avoid it ?

Comment: Why do you think you can avoid it and why would you need to avoid it? The limit of that expression is 1.

Comment: here is the code
lnL[j]=lnL[j]+y[i]*log(exp(x[i])/(1+exp(x[i])))+(1-y[i])*log(1/(exp(x[i])+1))
in the data of x there is x[i]=2000 and other big numbers which return an error because 1/(exp(x[i])+1) return 0

Comment: I'm sorry, but please use some elementary maths. `log(1/(exp(x[i])+1)))` is the same as `- x[i] - 1`.